# applying accelerometer sensor to my toy car

Tags: java, android

I have managed to control a handmade toy car, using my android app.

The controls I made are for manual drive, meaning i touch buttons to move the car by sending char to the arduino.

Now, i want to move on to the next level and use the accelerometer sensor. I have managed to get the readings of the x, y, z axis when i tilt my mobile, but i don't know what to do next.

I am facing 2 options:

1. Should i send the accelerometer values to the arduino, and let the arduino decide the speed (through PWM) and the which motor to start.
2. Use the android studio to compare the axes' values for example if the x-axis is more than 5, the app would send a character to the arduino that would make the car move forward with a desired speed.
   Here is the code i used to get the values, in the end i tried sending character 'F' to the arduino to move the car forward but nothing happened. I know there is no problem in sending code because i used the same in the manual drive activity (using buttons).

#### Code

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

    TextView tvX= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.x_axis);
    TextView tvY= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.y_axis);
    TextView tvZ= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.z_axis);

    Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;
    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
        float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
        float z = sensorEvent.values[2];
        last_x = x;
        last_y = y;
        last_z = z;

        tvX.setText(Float.toString(last_x));
        tvY.setText(Float.toString(last_y));
        tvZ.setText(Float.toString(last_z));

        if(last_x > 5f){
            if(btSocket!=null){
                try
                {
                    btSocket.getOutputStream().write("F".toString().getBytes());
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    msg("Error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```